# Database Design. Many to Many.What should be Primary Key?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, relationship

I am designing a university management system. I have 5 tables: Student, Teacher, Courses, Available_Courses and Taken_Courses.

```
Student:
    student_id (PK)

Teacher:
    teacher_id (PK)

Courses:
    courses_id (PK)

Available_Courses:
    available_courses_id
    teacher_id
    course_id

Courses_Taken:
    courses_taken_id
    student_id
    courses_available_id
```

What should be PK in Available-Courses and Courses_Taken table?

If I don't make available_courses_id (in Table Available_Courses) primary key then I will be unable to connect Courses_Table and if I make Composite key of all three attributes in table Available_Courses then one teacher can get registered with same course again and again. Making composite key of two attributes i.e. teacher_id and course_id will work but will increase repetition in my database as they both will also be in Courses_Taken Table to create relationship.

Same is with Courses_Taken Table as I need to use its PK in table Attendance (yet to be made).

So what should one do in such situation?

Comment: It seems like available_courses holds rows where a course is taught by a teacher. One would expect that the available courses would be the courses that have appear in some row in that table. Not that it matters to your question how define your tables, you just need to tell us the constraints that hold. (CKs, FDs, FKs).

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for an artificial key in the `available_courses` or `courses_taken` tables, just use a combination of the two foreign keys as a primary key:

```
student
    id          int unsigned(P)

teacher
    id          int unsigned(P)

course
    id          int unsigned(P)

available_courses
    teacher_id  int unsigned (F teacher.id)--\__(P)
    course_id   int unsigned (F course.id)---/

courses_taken
    student_id  int unsigned (F student.id)--\__(P)
    course_id   int unsigned (F course.id)---/
```

Comment: I know there is no need but lets say one needs to add another table named Exam_Results how would we integrate it in this design.
As far as i see we would need to repeat student.id, teacher.id and course.id in that new table named Exam_Results.
Is there another way around beside repeating?

Comment: @AzeemUllah There's nothing *wrong* with repeating them. Otherwise, you are repeating *ids* in *exactly the same places*. Redundancy is not about data appearing twice but *saying the same thing twice*.

Answer (score 0):

A CK (candidate key) is a set of columns unique in a table that doesn't contain a smaller unique column set. One CK can get called the PK (primary key).

What columns sets are unique depends on what the rows of your table say about your application situations and what application situations can arise.

Querying has nothing to do with "connecting tables" (whatever that means) or CKs or FKs (foreign keys). A query asks for rows that make true statements about the application situation built from what base table rows say about the application situation and how relation and logic operators combine them.

If columns form CKs or FKs (ie subrows of values for some list of columns are always present as subrow values for a particular CK) then we tell the DBMS so it can enforce that. That doesn't affect query composition.

There's nothing *wrong* per se with repeating values. Redundancy is not about data appearing twice but *saying the same thing twice*. There's not need to introduce an id column instead of natural keys. That just repeats *id* values in *exactly the same places*.

Assuming you use the ids, available_courses has CKs {available_courses_id} & {teacher_id, course_id} and courses_taken has CKs {courses_taken_id} & {student_id, courses_available_id}. (Although you don't need the ids.)